# Compile / submit iOS app with strings / text which should never reach of hackers

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, nsstring, pki

In our app we have several API keys (aka shared or private keys). Those are needed runtime. It is crucial that these strings never gets in the hand of anyone else but me / my organization.

**Attempt 1 - Do nothing**

```
NSString *privateKey = @"a6dedb6096973e4576e1dfc9d048075d;
```

If anyone gets hand of this app and gets pass the signing-stuff they can run `strings` on the binary and easily retreive all strings. (FAIL)

**Attempt 2 - Do something clever**

This is where you stackoverflow-guys are the best. Show me some magic!

Comment: Split up / obfuscate the key

Comment: This is a tricky issue without an easy solution.  One solution I've used in the past is to set up a separate, dedicated, internal web server whose ONLY purpose is to (a) store the private key, and (b) provide an internal web service (a simple CURL call in PHP) to perform any necessary functions with the private key.  Only those with permitted access to the private key have permitted access to the source code on *this* server.

Comment: If it is crucial that the keys never get into the hands of anyone else, then there is no safe way to distribute them and you should figure out a different way to achieve your goal. Security through obscurity (as suggested by Volker) is no security at all.

If the keys in question are for accessing services over the Internet there simply is no way to protect it. Anyone could sniff the network traffic from your application to determine the keys used.

You have not provided enough information in regards to the usage of the keys you wish to protect for a more detailed answer to your dilemma.

Comment: It's worth noting that if the code is written reasonably carefully with typical "do not allow direct file access" settings in `.htaccess`, it will be exceedingly difficult (if not impossible) for *external* hackers to access the private key from the outside world, since this is PHP code on your server.  The only 'hackers' who you need to worry about are programmers who already have (permitted) access to the source code, also having access to the private key.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I'm not sure why the ios-tag and the objective-c-tag was removed. I've updated my question. This is about iOS apps. Got nothing to do with PHP. :) I hope you can write new comments adressing iOS apps (not server apps).

Comment: I think your comments makes perfectly sense for web apps / php, though.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum can you delete your comments since you talk about PHP and not iOS?

Comment: These comments are independent of the programming language used.  PHP is a common example.  Question: Why are you storing private keys on the mobile device?  For iOS apps, my understanding is that the company's private keys do not need to be stored on the device.  They're stored on the server.  - but if you elaborate on your use case, and it turns out you *do* need to store your private keys on the device, I'll remove my comment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why would every copy of your app use the same private key?

Sending Data:
If your app need to send information to your server, it would only need the your public key to encrypt the data.

Receiving Data (This is where it gets tricky):
When the app is installed on the user's device, it should generate it's own private/public key pair.  Then it sends the public key to your server. (See above).  Then whenever the server needs to send data back to the device it would encrypt said data with the device's public key. Therefore only that device can decrypt the data.

Point is, if you put a know private key in the app what's the point.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has a write up on this site: [Securely storing OAuth keys in iOS application](https://sites.google.com/site/greateindiaclub/mobil-apps/ios/securelystoringoauthkeysiniosapplication).

They are storing the keys in a plist with AES Encryption. But I don't really see how that makes it safer.

Answer (score 0):

What we did the for Crystal Shuffle's private Facebook access keys, we hid the keys on a webservice. The iOS app would hit the service to get answers which the service could get since it had the key.

As far as I can tell, there is no secure way to include the key in the app itself.